# Writing numpy arrays to files

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to know if `numpy` has any build-in functions for writing to files or if there is a method, which should be used for writing an array constructed like this:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 6], [8, 7, 9]]
```

to a file so it looks like this:

```
2 3 4 
3 5 6
8 7 9
```

I am not sure how to this. I do know how to do it with a regular python list using a for loop but I want to know which way this should be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use

```
np.savetxt( "filename.txt", your_array )
```

For details see: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

**[Update]** You can use the formatting parameter e.g. like this:

```
your_array = [[2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 6], [8, 7, 9]]
np.savetxt("filename.txt", your_array, fmt="%d")
```

Comment: I don't know if I should use some additional parameters or how to make it write to file in this manner, but the array in the file I get with this code is in floats. I have an array with only integers like 123, 456,..., but the numbers in the output are 1,2300000, 4,56.....

Comment: Try it like this: np.savetxt("filename.txt", your_array, fmt="%d")